# Java/System Memory Issues - tomcat/rest/spring security/millions of data/Singleton ThreadPool

Tags: java, performance, spring-security, jersey, tomcat8

Below is the summary of the problem:

Application/System Details:
System configuration: 48 GB RAM/8 cores
Application Teck Stack: Jersey/Rest webservices application secured by spring security
other details: Tomcat/linux/mysql
Other specific code details: Using jdbc connection pool for database access. In our application, we submit a lot of asyncronous tasks. So, I'm using a singleton ThreadPoolExecutor. While getting the singleton, if the current queue length is zero, I'm ensuring to call shutDownImmediate and create a new ExecutorService so that it will garbage collect the old data.

Problem Summary:
We have a rest webservice that accepts CSV file input stream as input. Suppose if we receive a csv file of 1 million records, it is saved to db. Then it is split into 100 batches of 10K records each and then we submit an synchronous task for processing these sets of 10K records each in parallel. We submit the Asynchronous task to the Singleton ThreadPoolExecutor. Once the last thread has executed, I'm ensuring to call ExecutorService.showDownImmediate() and updating Singleton with new ThreadPoolExecutor.

**Each time, I process a new file containing 1 million records (CSV file size is 78 MB), the system ram/memory usage is going up by 8 GB. When I do the first million test the RAM usage went up from 21 GB to 29 GB. Then for each incremental 1 million test, the system kept blocking an additional 8 GB of RAM which is totally unusable. Even if I reboot the tomcat, still that memory is not freed up. So, system reboot is freeing up this memory.**

But, when building a real time scalable application with high availability, we cannot afford to restart the application quite often. I feel that this may not be an issue with java coding as java memory is getting freed up as soon as we complete running the last thread task (am saying this because I took the jhat outputs when the threads are running and after all threads have completed. I notice that the memory is freed up as soon as all tasks are complete). I feel that this has something to do with configuration.

Additional Points: 
Each batch goes through 3 phases of Asynchronous Tasks
0) As soon as users sends 1million.csv file, it is uploaded to db and a fileid is sent back to user. Internally it kicks off Async task (1)
1) Expects file id as input. It reads file from DB and then cuts into batches of 10K each and puts in batches
2) Expects batchId as input, it builds ArrayList from batchId and then does the processing
3) Expects batchId as input, it builds a different ArrayList and then does yet another kind of processing

The design may look bit hilarious in some aspects but I have my own functional/technical reasons to follow this approach. One more point why I'm highlighting this issue is that, initially I used to pass ArrayList as input to ASync Tasks which used to eat up lot lot more amount of memory. By passing fileid/batchid as input, I optimized memory to great extent and am also able to track success/error details at a more granular level. But still I have this final memory issue of 8 GB getting blocked up for each 1 million data load.

Can someone please suggest how to fine tune my application.

Comment: "I'm ensuring to call shutDownImmediate and create a new ExecutorService so that it will garbage collect the old data.". Well that's completely pointless.

Comment: Thanks Kayaman, Initially I did not implement the logic for shutdown/creating new service as it defies the purpose of singleton. But as I ran into serious performance problem, I'm just trying out various options to see how it goes.

Comment: Trying out things randomly is pointless. Why would you think an `ExecutorService` would hold on to any memory? Profile your application and stop guessing.

Comment: So you still keep guessing. Well, good luck with that.

Comment: I used jhat/jconsole and I noticed some huge memory leaks with my jdbc connection pool and I resolved the issue to some extent. Now, the memory leaks are <20 MB which belong to tomcat's org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader. But I think this coule be ignored. But still, I have one final issue.

Comment: I think you're using the term *memory leak* quite liberally. A memory leak ends with an `OutOfMemoryError`, but you seem to think that if a class allocates some memory that it's "leaked". Show the code you're using to insert data into the DB, maybe you're not closing your resources correctly.

Comment: You're not very experienced in profiling either are you. Don't blame the classloader, it's not the problem.